# show progress of render::rmarkdown in shiny

Tags: shiny, r-markdown

I have been working on a shiny app and within my action buttons I save  the output as html using render::rmarkdown() and its working perfect, however if I want to add with progress to the app, it doesnt count the rmarkdown saving time which is the actual waiting time for the user

sample of part of my problem:

```
test_fun <- function()
{
    for (i in 1:15) {
        incProgress(1/15)
        sum(runif(10000000,0,1))
    }
}
```

ui part:

```
sidebarLayout(
           sidebarPanel(
             actionButton("nplrhits", 'DSS top Hits')
           ),

           # Show a plot of the generated distribution
           mainPanel(
             plotlyOutput("nplrwfall")
```

server script:

```
observeEvent(input$nplrhits, {
   output$nplrwfall <- renderPlotly({
     withProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                  detail = 'This may take a while...', value = 0, {
                    test_fun()
                  })
     rmarkdown::render(paste0(dir_path,"/R_scripts/Hits_Waterfall.Rmd"), output_file = paste0(dir_path,"/results/Patient/",input$txt, "/Hits_Waterfall.html"))
     plotly::ggplotly(pn)}) 

   })
```